# How to enumerate subsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Can anyone tell me how to enumerate `\subsection`s? For example:

```
\subsection{Double-space a file.}
...
\subsection{Triple-space a file.}
...
```

I want this to look like:

```
1.1 Double-space a file.
...
1.2 Triple-space a file.
...
```

At the moment I only get this:

```
Double-space a file.
...
Triple-space a file.
...
```

Comment: This is unexpected behavior for the default setting. Perhaps you included something at the preamble that you didn't show. Minimal working example (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) will be very helpful.

Comment: If you just compile a minimal document like `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}` your output will look like this `1 Section
1.1 Subsection`. Therefore, you have included something to your document that changed the default behavior. Had you included a MWE you would have most likely found the culprit yourself, or would have made it possible for us to try help you better.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the level until which (sub)sections are numbered by setting the counter secnumdepth. `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{whatever}`

Comment: @Peteris: I think you misunderstand the answer. You should change the value of `secnumdepth` (to 2 or larger), not `subsection`.

Comment: @Peteris -- that's literally `secnumdepth`, not `subsection`. it should probably be `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` (if the depth for `chapter` is 1). see the documentation for `memoir` to determine the correct value.

Comment: @Peteris: you need to write `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}`. `secnumdepth` is the name of the counter (the section depth counter in this case) and `2` is for subsections (`0` for chapters, `1` for sections, `2` for subsections).

Comment: @Peteris: you're getting `1.0.1` because you did not create a `section` on top of your `subsection`. Are you sure you don't want your entries to be sections instead of subsections?

Comment: That said, you could probably do a `\numberwithin{subsection}{chapter}` but that'd be kind of an ugly approach.

Comment: @Peteris: Now if you want to tune the way sections look to make them look more like subsections, you can use the `titlesec` package.

Comment: @Raphink `memoir` provides its own methods for changing sections; although `titlesec` can be used with `memoir`, it's preferable not to.

Comment: @Alan: Good to know, I've never used `memoir`.

Comment: @Raphink `memoir` incorporates *a lot* of packages within the class directly: `abstract`, `appendix`, `array`, `booktabs`, `ccaption`, `chngcntr`, `crop`, `dcolumn`, `delarray`, `enumerate`, `epigraph`, `ifmtarg`, `ifpdf`, `index`, `makeidx`, `moreverb`, `needspace`, `newfile`, `nextpage`, `pagenote`, `patchcmd`, `parskip`, `setspace`, `shortvrb`, `showidx`, `tabularx`, `titleref`, `tocbibind`, `tocloft`, `verbatim` so you should be careful recommending packages to `memoir` users.

Comment: @Peteris Chap. 18 Sec 24 of the `memoir` manual.

Comment: @Peteris or check at the compilation's log file

Answer (score 6):

For memoir class the easier syntax is \setsecnumdepth{argument} (section 6.3 in the manual). In your case you would use

```
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
```

In case you want the Table Of Contents, to show up to subsections use

```
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
```

The argument of maxtocdepth can be different than setsecnumdepth. I think that this is the most usual case.